# string length is changed and wrong

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn Javascript and changed this program from w3schools, I though it must be correct but, whenever I click on the "try it", the value of the str.length is changed, and I can not understand why.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.length;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Visit Microsoft!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Is it `16`?

Comment: What do you mean it's changed? I mean, after you run the function, it's obviously changed because you replaced the text with a number...

Comment: Show the output in another container and it will stay 16

Comment: It's changing because your buttons `onclick` handler changes it.  What's the mystery?

Comment: @mplungjan This is easy to reproduce and not a typo...

Comment: `While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.` We both know there used to be a better version called "Too Localised"

Comment: I could also write my own: "Voting to close since the solution has already been given in the comments and should now be part of OPs JS vocabulary and not useful to future visitors. Answering this and getting voted up will block OP from deleting it"

Comment: @Paulpro Does this question answer a burning question many visitors will have? It is a copy of a w3schools code were the asker just needed to be shown how measuring the length of the content of a tag works. By all means let's keep it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171798/discussion-between-paulpro-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the innerHTML to the previous length, so the next time you press it you're getting the length of the length:

`'Visit Microsoft!'` has a length of `16`.

`'16'` has a length of `2`.

`'2'` has a length of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You change the `demo` innerHtml and again you read it from html code with this line

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.length;
```

So first you get `Visit Microsoft!` and its length is **16**.

you change the demo text to **16**. and again read its length and it is **2**. and again its length will be **1**.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the button, myFunction() is executed. When you click the first time, the variable str gets the value "Visit Microsoft!" and the content of the `<p>` tag with id "demo" becomes the length of the string in the variable str, so the length of "Visit Microsoft!", which is 16, and you will see 16.
The next time you click the button, the variable str gets the value "16" and the content of the `<p>` tag with id "demo" becomes the length of the string in the variable str, so the length of "16", which is 2. And so on...